# how to write a normal query in mysql in the form that we use in model in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

how to write a normal query that we use in mysql in the form that we use in model in codeigniter can someone help me.

```
$sql = "SELECT gender,
               SUM(CASE WHEN Handedness = 'Left-handed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) left_handed,
               SUM(CASE WHEN Handedness = 'Right-handed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) right_handed,
               COUNT(*) total
          FROM Table1
         GROUP BY gender WITH ROLLUP";
$data = $this->db->query($sql)->result_array();
```

how to write this in the form that we use in model in codeigniter that is

```
$this->db->select('financial_year');
        $this->db->from('historical_data');
        $this->db->where("financial_year BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to'");
        $this->db->group_by('financial_year');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

See if it works.

```
$this->db->select("gender, SUM(CASE WHEN Handedness = 'Left-handed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) left_handed, SUM(CASE WHEN Handedness = 'Right-handed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) right_handed, COUNT(*) total", false)->group_by('gender WITH ROLLUP')->get('Table1')->result_array();
```

**EDIT BASED ON THE ERROR YOU GOT:**

```
$this->db->select("question_no, SUM(CASE WHEN organization_answer_rating = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 1, SUM(CASE WHEN organization_answer_rating = '2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 2, COUNT(*) as total", false)->group_by('question_no WITH ROLLUP')->get('questionnaire')->result_array();
```

Comment: am getting the following error Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1, SUM(CASE WHEN organization_answer_rating = '2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 2, COUNT(*)' at line 1

SELECT question_no, SUM(CASE WHEN organization_answer_rating = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 1, SUM(CASE WHEN organization_answer_rating = '2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 2, COUNT(*) total FROM (`questionnaire`) GROUP BY `question_no` WITH ROLLUP

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\gptw\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330

Comment: hi Nil'z help me please

Comment: I dont think the error you posted is generated by the query I posted @user2739848.

Comment: then what was the reason for that

Comment: that means what is the problem

Comment: yeah you are right  Nil'z i removed 1 and 2 outside braces and it worked

Comment: i need one more help will you do that please

Comment: Accept the answer if it helped you and sure post your question I will definitely help you. @user2739848

Comment: i need to find mean for the databse values in codeigniter can you please say how to do that please